# List manipulation after importing txt-file

Tags: list-manipulation

I have some problems converting data which I imported from a txt-file into proper Mathematica expressions. After importing my data looks like

```
sample = {"{3", "\"string1\"", 45, "\"string2\"", 8.32, " {2013", 8, 1, 0, 6, " 19}", "0.}"}
```

Now I would like to transform it into

```
converted = {3, "string1", 45, "string2", 8.32`, {2013, 8, 1, 0, 6, 19}, 0.}
```

I imported the file using `Import[file.txt,"Data"]`

Comment: If you provide a sample from file.txt we might be able to make `Import` do a part of the job for you.

Comment: Try to import as `"Package"`, not `"Data"` if you have a list written using Mathematica syntax.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can `Map` with this:

```
ToExpression[StringJoin @@ Riffle[ToString /@ sample, ","]]
```

> ```
> {3, "string1", 45, "string2", 8.32`, {2013, 8, 1, 0, 6, 19}, 0.`}
> ```

Comment: Thanks for the elegant solution, solved my problem entirely

Comment: @Kuba, Nice solution, but I wander: If this oddly shaped "sample" was imported from a text file, Wouldn't probably  be better to parse the data correctly in the first instance, instead of correcting it afterwards?

Comment: @rhermans That's what Pickett and Szabolcs are suggesting, I agree but OP has not responded to the comments.

Answer (score 4):

Another solution without the use of `Riffle` :

```
ToExpression@StringReplace[ToString[sample], {"\\" -> "", "{{" -> "{", "}}" -> "}"}]
```

Comment: Congratulations on your fanatic badge :) (temporary message)

Comment: Thank you!(permanent message):-P